# Suppress javascript popup by referrer?

Tags: javascript, colorbox

```
<!-- Code for Pop-up -->
<script type="text/javascript">
if (document.cookie.indexOf('visited=true') === -1) {
var expires = new Date();
expires.setDate(expires.getDate()+30);
document.cookie = "visited=true; expires="+expires.toUTCString();
$(document).ready(function(){
setTimeout(function(){
$.colorbox({width:"650", height:"680", inline:true, href:"#inline_content"})
}, 3000);
});
}
</script>
```

The above script serves a popup intended for first time in a long time visitors to my eCommerce site. It is in the footer so it serves on any entry page. What I'd like to be able to do though is suppress the popup if the visitor follows a link from my separate email campaign. Does anyone have a recommendation? Maybe be identifying something in the utm tag that would still set the cookie but suppress the popup?

Comment: There’s always not showing the popup, because popups are stupid and annoying to click through.

Comment: Have you looked at how to get the referrer? Seems like a logical place to start.